# Autocompletion library in C++

Tags: c++, ubuntu, autocomplete, debian

I need an auto-completion routine or library in C++ for 1 million words. I guess I can find a routine on the net like Rabin–Karp. Do you know a library that does this. I don't see it in Boost.

Also, is it a crazy idea to use MySql LIKE SQL request to do that ?

Thank you

EDIT: It is true that it is more suggestions than auto-completion that I need (propose ten words when the user typed the first 2 letters). I actually also have expressions "Nikon digital camera". But for a first version, I only need suggestions on "Ni" of Nikon and not on "digital camera".

Comment: A million?  Really?  English only has 150,000 words in active use, as an example.

Comment: @Joe, my test English dictionary contains 329380 words.

Comment: @Kirill: yes, but how many do you need autocomplete for?   Also: http://oxforddictionaries.com/page/93

Comment: For security purposes, you often want to use forms derivated (conjugated, plurals), surnames and a few common languages mixed, thus raising quickly the number to check.

Comment: @Joe: who said it was for the English language, or that only one language would be used ? I agree a million seems overkill, but since we don't know about the OP's requirements...

Comment: @Matthieu, that's why it says "as an example".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use any crazy algorithm if you begin by preparing an index.

A simple Trie/Binary Search Tree structure, that keeps the words ordered alphabetically, would allow efficient prefix searches.

In C++, for example, the `std::map` class has the `lower_bound` member which would point in O(log N) to the first element that could possibly extend your word.

Comment: OK, I'll start this way and see where it goes. If it's not good enough I will implement something better

Answer (score 2):

hmmmm, if you're thinking about using like, it means that most probably, you want to have classical autocompletion (begin of word is matching).

What about organising (nicely) your data into a 26-tree (one entry per letter, or if you support other than letters, an well chosen x-tree). That way, you organize your data once and then, you have quick result by tree parsing. if you want to limit the amount of results proposed into your autocompletion, you can adapt your tree parsing algorithm. Seems simple and efficient (a like syntax in SQL will have to compare all your items in your table each time, whereas my solution is much quicker once the data is correctly set)

Other solution, you can peek at Qt implementation of [QCompleter](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcompleter.html) (might be overkill to depend on Qt on your code, I don't know)

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a project once that did something like this using [CLucene](http://clucene.sourceforge.net/).  It worked fine.

Comment: Why Lucene or Solr with 1 million documents of one expression would be better than MySQL since it is just a simple list of words. I am not indexing 3 pages articles. I don't need facets.

Comment: Lucene supports synonyms and a lot more stuff. If you only need a bare trie, by all means use that. But as your needs grow I imagine you may start wanting more features. And Lucene is easy enough to try.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a trie (prefix tree) to store your words.

```
struct trie
{
  std::map<char, trie*> next;
  bool is_word;

  void insert(std::string w)
  {  
    trie * n = this;
    for (int i = 0; i < w.size(); ++i) {
      if (n->next.find(w[i]) == n->next.end()) {
        n->next[w[i]] = new trie();
      }
      n = n->next[w[i]];
    }
    n->is_word = true;
  }
};
```

Then you can easily get prefix matches iterating on subtrees.

Comment: `std::map` may be good enough. Note that here you get to the first match in O(1).

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own simple auto-completion function with using Damerau-Levenshtein distance.

Comment: I don't see how that could be both simple and fast at the same time. You'd have to implement Levenshtein automata, right?

Comment: This distance is mostly used for typo-correction. For auto-completion I surmise a simple prefix-based mechanism would work.

Comment: @Matthieu M., agree, probably something like [trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) would be a better choice. It requires additional memory, but will be much faster.

Comment: V.: I've seen (and developped) nice custom implementations of Trie. You can use "buckets" to compress the leaves (using a single sorted array with a given number of entries) and you can "group" the symbols of the alphabet to reduce the branching factor for the nodes (I used static grouping for ease of use). And then there is the Patricia Trie with path-compression. It really is a fascinating data structure :)